# Microsoft Translator oAuth call for token generation timeout

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've deployed a Microsoft-Cognitive Translator Text API environment in Azure. I've been following the documentation, and landed on the `Getting a token on this interactive page` section. Inserting my private key in the field has the process wait very long and fail, most of the time. I was able to get a result a few times, but it's very rare.

Using the command line curls, I've been getting 500s, or SSLRead errors. Is the service down ATM, or was it moved to somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/:

> 2/14 Cognitive Services | Resolved
>
> Summary of impact: Between as early as 22:00 UTC on 13 Feb 2017 and
>   4:00 UTC on 14 Feb 2017, a subset of customers using Cognitive
>   Services may have received intermittent timeouts or errors when making
>   API requests or generating tokens for their Cognitive Services.
>
> Preliminary root cause: At this stage Engineers do not have a
>   definitive root cause.
>
> Mitigation: Engineers scaled out the service in order to mitigate.
>
> Next steps: Engineers will continue to investigate to establish the
>   full root cause.